# Efficient looping

Tags: php, html-table

I have a table:

```
| header_row | cell_usr_a | cell_usr_b | cell_fixed_a | cell_fixed_b |
| second_row |...
| usr_row_a  |...
| usr_row_b  |...
| usr_row_c  |...
```

The first two **columns** in this example (cell_usr*) come from a dynamic object (an array of x entries); there could be 0 or many of those; the last two columns are always there.

The first two rows are always there (element name, and other general properties).
The usr_row* depend on elements in the dynamic object: if one of the element of the array has the correspondent property set, I show the row, otherwise I don't.

How can I efficiently iterate through the object without having to re-iterate for every row?

Currently I do

```
foreach ($array as $element)
```

for every row, adding  according to the size of $array.
Then I would need to first iterate through all the $element again to see if the usr_row property is set, and if yes, construct the row...

Any idea on how to do this efficiently (and possibly elegantly)?
It does not necessarily to be a table by the way.

EDIT: some more code to help illustrate my question
$packages is the object, it's basically an array with unknown number of elements

```
 <table>
    <tr><!-- header row -->
             <td>Package name</td>
            <?php foreach($packages as $pkg) {
               echo '<td>'.$pkg->package_name . '</td>';
            } ?>
            <td>fixed value</td><!-- cell_fixed_a -->
            <td>no value</td><!-- cell_fixed_b -->
          </tr>
          <tr><!-- second row -->
            <td>Count</td>
            <?php foreach($packages as $pkg) {
               echo '<td>'.$pkg->count . '</td>';
            } ?>
            <td>fixed value</td><!-- cell_fixed_a -->
            <td>fixed value</td><!-- cell_fixed_b -->
          </tr>
          <tr><!-- usr_row_a 
               HERE I ONLY NEED TO HAVE THIS ROW IF any one of $pkg has prop set
               -->
            <?php foreach($packages as $pkg) {
              if ($pkg->prop) {
                echo '<tr><td>Property name</td>';
                echo '<td>'. $pkg->prop . '</td>';
            }
         </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: It's quite difficult to visualise what you are asking - can you show some code? Also the thought occurs this might be better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($your_object)`?

Comment: Can you add more information on your array structure and desired output using print_r so that i can get a better picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to loop  through `$packages` 3 times .. you can just save the result in variables

```
$name = "";
$count = "";
$property = "";

foreach ( $packages as $pkg ) {
    $name .= '<td>' . $pkg->package_name . '</td>';
    $count .= '<td>' . $pkg->count . '</td>';

    if ($pkg->prop) {
        $property .= '<tr><td>Property name</td>';
        $property .= '<td>' . $pkg->prop . '</td>';
    }
}
```

you can `echo` them is respective places ...